# Simple media query will not resize div or change font in chrome or IE

Tags: html, css

This very simple media query, which I have pared down hoping to find the culprit, the div 'all' will not resize in Chrome or IE. Oddly it works in FF. I have tried every formulation of the actual media query. Any help appreciated.

Here is some of the HTML

```
<div class="all">
Adipiscing accumsan at habitasse pharetra eu a magna sollicitudin ...</div>
```

> Here is the CSS

```
body {

  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: white;

}

.all {

  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 300px;
  background: blue;

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
       .all {
        width: 690px;
        font-size: 30px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Works for me in Chrome here; http://codepen.io/robertspier/pen/gwymGP

Comment: What you've written will make `.all` have a width of 690px on small screens, and when the screen goes over 700px in width will resize to 200px, is that expected?

Comment: Hmm. I would think it's my broken browser, but it doesn't work in Chrome on my tablet or phone either.

Comment: Yes I meant to say I changed the sizes for testing purposes to make it really really obvious. My real sizes are narrow for desktop and wider for phone. Was using percentages, and when that didn't work, thought I'd try pixels. still nothing.

Comment: Works for me. Perhaps there's something up with the media-type. Is there more to the page you are testing than just the example given here? I think the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove the static width from your media query. Make it 100% or less as I've done in this example. The way you have written it, on smaller screens the div will always be 690px wide.

```css
body {

  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: white;

}

.all {

  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  background: blue;

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
       .all {
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 30px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="all">
Adipiscing accumsan at habitasse pharetra eu a magna sollicitudin ...</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I was using percentages. 65% for screens over 700px and 90% for screens smaller. When % didn't work I tried this to see what could be causing this problem. On my Galaxy s5 and in the chrome inspector, it just does not work no matter what units I use.

Comment: Does it work here...i.e. full width of the board at under 700px? It doesn't for me http://nancymichell.us/cscie3/words.html

Comment: Try media screen instead of media only screen and it should work. Also I just checked and it's working for me at 700 the green grid goes to 100% with some margin on either side. Make sure you clear your browser cache so it loads the updated css too.

Comment: I validated your html and you are missing a Doctype which will definitely give you varied results in different browsers. Go here to see the errors you need to fix: http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fnancymichell.us%2Fcscie3%2Fwords.html

Comment: I wish I could vote for the correct answer but I never got it working. Will start from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine, but maybe you're mixed up. I think you want the small one on the media query.

```
body {

  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: white;

}

.all {

  width: 690px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 300px;
  background: blue;

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
       .all {
        width: 200px;
        font-size: 30px;
    }
}
```

http://codepen.io/paulcredmond/pen/NRmpXp